# Unable to Shrink ubuntu root partition on vmware

Tags: resize, partition, shrink

I am Using Ubuntu 14.04 Server as VMware Guest OS.
I have allocated 200 GB Disk space of thin provision disk.
I only using 100 Gb of Disk space. I need shrink the  remaining
Disk space. I tried with Gparted but in that not showing free space
and partition is locked icon.

Kindly help us to resolve the issue.
thanks in advance
Jagadeesh

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't shrink it with gparted. Use the lvm tools instead. Here is a useful link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/124465/how-do-i-shrink-the-root-logical-volume-lv-on-lvm

Comment: HI thanks a lot for you help. I worked inside Ubunut and size of root partition is reduced. But in VMware Provisioned and allocated disk space still showing 200gb. How to reduce this in vmware.